# "folder contents could not be displayed." error when trying to plug in a Galaxy Nexus

Tags: 12.10, android, mtp

Tried to connect Galaxy Nexus to Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, I choose open folder from a pop up dialog box and it says the following error:

> The folder contents could not be displayed.
>
> Sorry, could not display all the contents of "Galaxy Nexus". Timeout was reached

Anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have had that issue.

MTP support is not all that great. I recommend using either SSHDroid or DroidNAS and connecting over more "stable" protocols.

If you really want to use MTP. Then make sure that the nexus is on, with the screen on, and not locked. If the screen is locked, MTP access is disabled.

Comment: thanks man, will try SSHDroid and it seems nice.. but still I want to take advantage of cable over wifi

Comment: I have used **SSHDroid** (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid&hl=en) extensively with Ubuntu 12.10 and **Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0)**. Was able to connect over command line (SSH) or using GUI (Nautilus) with **no** issues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my Ubuntu works like a charm with my Google Nexus, update your MTP support from the following [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/gvfs-libmtp):

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gvfs-libmtp
$sudo apt-get update
```

Install everything comes along with that ppa update, follow up with the machine reboot and you are done!

After that, I can see my Google Nexus folder structure and able to copy any big files to Nexus without problem from Nautilus.

Credit goes to [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html) team!

Comment: This now says "Don't use this PPA!  Add https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp instead!"  So the command to add it is `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp`.